# Android: How to add a context menu to the item of a gridview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-contextmenu

I have a grid view , it's item  is formed by an icon and tow textview. the code of my item is given below. I would like  to add a context menu for each item, like this used in google playstore as mentioned by the image [link for the image](http://s30.postimg.org/z070fez5t/googleplay.png)

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/round_boutton"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="TextView1"
                android:textColor="@color/orangemill"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView2" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: registerForContextMenu

Comment: @pskink thanks but if you look to this used in googleplay it is not OnItemLongClickListener. their is oncliklistener with a menu icon that use a simple onclicklistener.

Comment: so use onclicklistener if you dont want std context menu

Comment: how to implement two Action listener for one item, the first launch the application the second a contextmenu, i will add an image botton menu exactly us googleplay.

Answer (score 0):

create click listener for the menu button/image on the grid item adapter class and add the code to create,show popup menu.
Then implement MenuItem click listener for the activity.

```
holder.menu_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(Activity.this, view);
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(Activity.this);
                    popupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_item);
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
            });
```

Then implement MenuItem Selection

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:
               //your code
            break;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                //your code
                return true;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Add implements `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener on the Activity.`
Try this...